# sql query to group same values from one column based on condition

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

Based on this table

```
Field1 field2 field3
10     x      10.x.value
10     y      10.x.valua
11     x      11.x.value
11     y      11.x.value
```

for each Field1 (10 and 11) ... check for x and y values (field3). 
If even 1 fails, the field1 is not useful

So I get this

```
Field   index1       index2 
10      10.x.value   10.y.value  
11      11.x.value   11.y.value
```

I have this sql so far

```
select distinct a.id as 'Id Arquivo', b.idIndice, b.valor from tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a
join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as b on a.id = b.idDocumento
join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType as c on a.idDocType = c.id
join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as d on c.id = d.docTypeId
where d.docTypeId = 40 and (b.idIndice = 11 AND b.valor = '11111111' OR b.idIndice = 12 AND b.valor = '11111' )
```

**EDIT:**

This is my result set

```
id  idIndice    valor
13  11          11111111
13  12          11111
14  11          11111111
14  12          11111
16  12          11111
```

Index 16 has no idIndice 11 = '11111111'
so it should not be displayed

Comment: What's the result of your query?

Answer (score 1):

Edit #1: based on your edit you might be able to use something like this:

```
select a.id as 'Id Arquivo', 
    b.idIndice, 
    b.valor
from tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a
join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as b 
    on a.id = b.idDocumento
join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType as c 
    on a.idDocType = c.id
join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as d 
    on c.id = d.docTypeId
where d.docTypeId = 40 
    and (b.idIndice = 11 AND b.valor = '11111111' 
         OR b.idIndice = 12 AND b.valor = '11111')
group by a.id, b.idIndice, b.valor
having count(distinct b.idIndice) = 2
```

<strike>While it is not exactly clear what you are trying to do. It looks like you want to `PIVOT` the data similar to this:</strike>

```
select *
from
(
  select distinct a.id as 'Id Arquivo', 
    --b.idIndice, 
    b.valor,
    'index'+cast(row_number() over(partition by a.id order by b.idIndice) as varchar(10)) rn
  from tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a
  join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as b 
    on a.id = b.idDocumento
  join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType as c 
    on a.idDocType = c.id
  join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as d 
    on c.id = d.docTypeId
  where d.docTypeId = 40 
    and (b.idIndice = 11 AND b.valor = '11111111' 
         OR b.idIndice = 12 AND b.valor = '11111')
) src
pivot
(
  max(valor)
  for rn in (Index1, Index2)
) piv
```

Comment: Edited my question and now you can see the problem. This solution does not solve the problem

Comment: This does not return anything.

Comment: @user1918834 can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your tables and some sample data?